# 2 canvasjs chart in one pageproblem,

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, charts, canvasjs

i tried to put 2 Canvasjs chart in one html page. i have included jquery, and it works when i put only one chart div, once i add second chart, it show error, only show up one chart.

I want to show 2 or more chart in a page, is it possible?

here's my code. thank you

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="canvas/js/jquery.canvasjs.min.js"></script>
  
  <!FIRST JAVASCRIPT>
  <script type="text/javascript">
      window.onload = function () {
          var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
              data: [
              {
                  type: "column",
                  dataPoints: [
                  { x: 10, y: 10 },
                  { x: 20, y: 15 },
                  { x: 30, y: 25 },
                  { x: 40, y: 30 },
                  { x: 50, y: 28 }
                  ]
              }
              ]
          });
 
          chart.render();
      }
  </script>
  <!SECOND JAVASCRIPT>
  <script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function () {
    var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer2");

    chart.options.axisY = { prefix: "$", suffix: "K" };
    chart.options.title = { text: "Fruits sold in First & Second Quarter" };

    var series1 = { //dataSeries - first quarter
        type: "column",
        name: "First Quarter",
        showInLegend: true
    };

    var series2 = { //dataSeries - second quarter
        type: "column",
        name: "Second Quarter",
        showInLegend: true
    };

    chart.options.data = [];
    chart.options.data.push(series1);
    chart.options.data.push(series2);


    series1.dataPoints = [
            { label: "banana", y: 18 },
            { label: "orange", y: 29 },
            { label: "apple", y: 40 },
            { label: "mango", y: 34 },
            { label: "grape", y: 24 }
    ];

    series2.dataPoints = [
        { label: "banana", y: 23 },
        { label: "orange", y: 33 },
        { label: "apple", y: 48 },
        { label: "mango", y: 37 },
        { label: "grape", y: 20 }
    ];

    chart.render();
}
</script>
  
  
  
  
</head>
 
<body>
  <!FIRST CHART SHOW>
  <div id="chartContainer1" style="height: 500px; width: 50%;"></div>
  <!SECOND CHART SHOW>
  <div id="chartContainer2" style="height: 500px; width: 50%;"></div>
  
  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please [edit] to add a more specific problem statement. What error message do you get?

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, you don't need two window.onload functions. The second onload function will override the first one. So just have one and include both the charts code in the one of them.

Also, the first chart being created requires an element with id as `chartContainer` which is not present in the DOM. Replace that with `chartContainer1`.

Replace

```
var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {...});
```

with

```
var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer1", {...});
```

Instead of using one variable `chart` for both the charts use two variables so that the variable is not overridden. Something like this

```
window.onload = function(){
  var chart1 = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer1", {
    data: [{
      type: "column",
      dataPoints: [{
        x: 10,
        y: 10
      }, {
        x: 20,
        y: 15
      }, {
        x: 30,
        y: 25
      }, {
        x: 40,
        y: 30
      }, {
        x: 50,
        y: 28
      }]
    }]
  });

  chart1.render();

  var chart2 = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer2");

  chart2.options.axisY = {
    prefix: "$",
    suffix: "K"
  };
  chart2.options.title = {
    text: "Fruits sold in First & Second Quarter"
  };

  var series1 = { //dataSeries - first quarter
    type: "column",
    name: "First Quarter",
    showInLegend: true
  };

  var series2 = { //dataSeries - second quarter
    type: "column",
    name: "Second Quarter",
    showInLegend: true
  };

  chart2.options.data = [];
  chart2.options.data.push(series1);
  chart2.options.data.push(series2);


  series1.dataPoints = [{
    label: "banana",
    y: 18
  }, {
    label: "orange",
    y: 29
  }, {
    label: "apple",
    y: 40
  }, {
    label: "mango",
    y: 34
  }, {
    label: "grape",
    y: 24
  }];

  series2.dataPoints = [{
    label: "banana",
    y: 23
  }, {
    label: "orange",
    y: 33
  }, {
    label: "apple",
    y: 48
  }, {
    label: "mango",
    y: 37
  }, {
    label: "grape",
    y: 20
  }];

  chart2.render();
};
```

Here is a demo **http://jsbin.com/rocusuhevo/edit?html,js,output**

Comment: Thank you so much, finally I know what's going on, i think you really show me a clear direction. thank you